# How to deploy SQL Server 2008 R2 on target machine?

Tags: deployment, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been using SQL Server 2000 for a few years. For the deployment of SQL Server 2000 I was using MSDE (Microsoft Desktop Engine 2000) on target machine.

Now I have switched over to SQL Server 2008 R2. I have develop an application by using SQL Server 2008 R2 as my database. Now I am confused about the deployment of this app.

I have searched for MSDE 2008 R2 but could not find it. Will anyone please tell me that what should I use in the place of MSDE 2000?

Answer (score 0):

The replacement for MSDE as of versions 2005 and newer is SQL Server **Express**.

[See more about SQL Server 2012 Express here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).

You can also still download the [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express version here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650)